# Perform OAUTH2.0 authentication in greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, rest, oauth-2.0, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am new to javascript and jquery.I wish to query a REST API from a greasemonkey script that uses OAUTH 2.0 to authorize.

My question is-

> How do I perform the OAUTH 2.0 authentication from a greasemonkey script ? Is there some pre-existing script that I can include and call its functions directly to get/refresh access-tokens ? If not, how can I write the script for this from scratch ?

Any sort of help would be great.